# "sorry, too many clients already" error raised with PostgreSQL (w/ TimescaleDB extension) pool and nodeJS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, timescaledb

I have a nodeJS application that extensively interacts with the database (PostgreSQL w/ TimescaleDB extension) and I have trouble with the "sorry, too many clients already" error being raised despite using a Pool.

I am 99% sure that clients are released when needed and even if they are not, newly created ones should wait forever instead of throwing an error.

Methods that interact with the database are constructed this way:

```
return this.timescalePool.connect()
      .then((timescaleClient) => timescaleClient.query(“myQuery”)
        .then((res) => {
          timescaleClient.release();
          // code
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          try {
            // Avoid throwing an error when the client has already been released.
            timescaleClient.release() ;
          } catch (err) {}

         // code
        })
```

The current configuration for the postgres max_connection is 250 and 75 for the pool size.

What could be the reasons of having the "too many clients" error despite using a pool ?
What is the best option for live monitoring the behaviour of the pool / clients and have a better understanding of what is happening ?

Comment: What does pg_stat_activity show?  Could there be multiple instances of the pool running, each trying to use 75 connections?  Some things bypassing the pool to connect directly?

Comment: Thanks, I think that the issue what multiple pools were created within the app. So the error was raised by new pool trying to get clients.